# ethereum.org/crowdsale ALSO FOR USER TOKENS?

Tags: tokens, tutorials

The information of the webpage says something about crowdsale/equity token. Since the token I want to distribute is a user/utility token; is this a good source to learn the code?

If not, what would be a good source to retrieve information about issuing a user token?

Comment: What do you refer to by using the term "user/utility token"? What is the difference to a crowdsale/equity token?

Comment: @gisdev_p a user token is a token that is necessary in order to acces a service. An equity token is comparable to a stock of a company/project (and thus an security which is heavily regulated by the SEC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens that are created based on Ethereum usually serve two purposes: either to obtain funds or to be used as a currency with that a user can pay for the service the platform offers, sometimes they serve both purposes at the same time. So if I understand your question right, this could be relevant for your purpose.

As far as I know the discussion, however, it is not simply enough to define a token as a user token in order not to have the risk of regulation or even violating regulations yet to come. The criteria rather seems to be if the token you are selling is already usable during the sale, or only after the sale is over. If you are interested in that, the issue is discussed in this [post](https://blog.colony.io/the-colony-token-sale-7ac14c845bc0).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm familiar what you are saying but since I'm living in Europe that will not be an criteria. I will therefore also exclude US citizens from partaking in the token sale.